# TikZ - Callout position relative to the text

Tags: tikz-pgf, callout

Given this minimum compilable example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{hobby}
    \usetikzlibrary{ocgx}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=.5ex]\node(#1){};}

\newcounter{contatoreRiquadri}
\setcounter{contatoreRiquadri}{1}

\tikzset{stileCallout/.style={
    draw=gray,
    thick,
    rectangle callout,
    anchor=pointer,
    align=justify,
    fill=gray!17}
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\parolaLinkRiquadro}{r[] m}{%
    \switchocg{#1}{\textsf{\textcolor{gray}{#2}}}\tikzmark{#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\riquadroEsplicativo}{O{opacity=1,text opacity=1} m O{270:1cm} m O{5cm} m m}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=#2,status=invisible,name={#4}}]
\node[stileCallout,text width=#5,callout relative pointer={(#3)},#1] at (#2) {\textcolor{black}{\textbf{``}\,#4\,\textbf{''.}}\par\centering\href{#6}{#7}\par};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\riquadro}{m O{opacity=1,text opacity=1} m O{270:1cm} m O{5cm}}{%
    \parolaLinkRiquadro[riquadro\thecontatoreRiquadri]{\textsf{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}}%
    \riquadroEsplicativo[#2]{riquadro\thecontatoreRiquadri}[#4]{#3}[#6]{#5}{#1}%
    \addtocounter{contatoreRiquadri}{1}%
    }



\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\riquadro{\textbf{CLICK HERE!}}
    {long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text}
    [180:1cm]{and than click here}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

If I put as the second optional argument of `\riquadro` `[270:1cm]` the callout is written <del>above</del> **in front of** the text, if I put `[90:1cm]` it is drawn <del>below</del> **behind** the text. What can I do so that is *always* drawn **in front of** the text.

---

---

[image]

Comment: well keep it `[270:1cm]` and it would always be above. I think I don't get your question.

Comment: The problem is that in some cases I'm forced to use a different value than `[270:1cm].` For example, if the word the you must to click it's close to the top edge of the page, you can't use `[270:1cm].` I need a solution that goes well with `[90:1cm].` Thank you!

Comment: But isn't the `90` or `270` just the angle of the callout relative to the callout? So `270` is below i.e. above the text and `90` is above i.e. below the text.

Comment: No, with `270` degree the callout is above the word you click. With `90` degrees, is below. The fact is that the callout is drawn *before* writing the text that follows the word you click. So with `270` degree remains above the text, while with `90` remains below. I want that with any value of the angle, the frame remain *above* the text. Compiling the code that I quoted you will understand what I mean (maybe I can explain my problem in terms of layers). Thank you!

Comment: I think there is a confusion here. You are referencing a tikzmark inside an ocg layer. It doesn't decide where it show up depending on the angle, it just follows the relative angle so there is no problem there. It is because you use `at (#2)` for the positioning. And your use case as you explain means you want absolute pointer not a relative one. Because it can't know whether it's the top of the page. I think the question does not reflect what you are having problem with.

Comment: I think it's simpler so: in the example code that I wrote appears `\riquadro{\textbf{CLICK HERE!}}{Testo di prova. Testo di prova.}[90:1cm]{Terzo argomento.}.` Compiling the sample with `[270:1cm]` instead of `[90:1cm].` How do I make that I have the same behavior and the callout to cover the text in all cases? So you understand? Sorry for my english. Thank you!

Comment: @percusse the more I reread the comment the more I get confused. Can I vote to close this question?

Comment: Nevermind. **above** means in front of the text.